# /lib folder has a moduel test_module.rb, how to reference from my User.rb model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In /lib I have a test_module.rb file with:

```
require 'digest'
module TestModule

  def encrypt(string)
       Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
  end

end
```

Now in my User.rb I have:

```
class user < ActiveRecord:Base

   before_save   :set_password


   private

     def set_password
         self.encrypted_password = TestModule::encrypt(password)
     end


end
```

How can I get access to this method, right now I'm getting an error saying encrypt is not a method (undefined).

Do I require or include this module?

I just want to call the method ecrypt like its a static method really, advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `def encrypt` in your module, do `def self.encrypt`. Explaining this the easy way, prefixing the name with self will make it a static function. Its actually a bit more complex then that, you are defining encrypt on the singleton class of the instance of Module stored in the constant TestModule, but that sort of thing is squarely in advanced ruby territory. You can think of self methods as static and not really get into any trouble.

Comment: so then I just use require 'testmodule' or test_module or?

Comment: if you are using rails 2, it should just work. rails 3 they dropped lib from the autoload path, so you need to do something like require "#{Rails.root}/lib/test_module". Or add lib back in to the autoload path http://hemju.com/2010/09/22/rails-3-quicktip-autoload-lib-directory-including-all-subdirectories/

Comment: @matt..Why did they drop /lib from autoload path?..it was a nice default to have..

Comment: apparently a lot of people didn't realize they didn't need to require manually if they would just name their stuff right. Their reasoning was it is easy to add in for people who are familiar with rails, and if newbies dont realize how autoload works, it will just cause more confusion then good. I don't really agree with that, but it really isn't too hard to add it back in to the load paths.

Comment: @matt..yeah..it isnt hard to add it back but the name /lib itself suggests that it is the library needed for the app and it will be autoloaded.